# Process messages from Azure in LIFO

Tags: rest, azure, cloud

I am using the Azure REST API to read messages from an Azure Queue using Peek-Lock Message. Is there any way I can read the last message that was posted in the queue rather than reading from a queue based mechanism (FIFO)?

Also, is there a faster way to process messages from Azure other than using the Peek-Lock Message REST API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can read the last message that was posted in the
>   queue rather than reading from a queue based mechanism (FIFO)?

Using the REST API, unfortunately there's no way to process the last message first. You would have to implement something on your own. If you know that your queue can't have more than 32 messages at a time, you could possibly get all 32 messages in one go and sort them on the client side based on the message insertion time. Yet another (crazy) idea would be to create a new queue for each message and name the queue using the following pattern: "q"-(DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks). Now list queues and get only the 1st queue. This will give you the message you last inserted.

> Also, is there a faster way to process messages from Azure other than
>   using the Peek-Lock Message REST API?

One possibility could be to fetch more than one messages from a queue and process them in parallel on the client side.